# Removing User with Mongoose & MongoDB

Tags: mongodb, mongoose

```
app.post("/delete", function(req,res){
    var deluser = req.body.usernamedel;
    var reason = req.body.reason;
    User.remove({name: deluser}, function(err, user){
        if(err){
            console.log(err)
        } else {
            console.log(user);
        }
    }).exec();
});
```

I'm trying to get this post request to pull the name from the page and then remove it from the database, but it doesn't seem to remove it. All it shows in the console is this -`{ n: 0, ok: 1 }`- which I don't know what means. How do I make the command actually delete the user?

Comment: What it means is the `n: 0` essentially says that **nothing** actually matched the query condition given in argument, so there is no data in your collection matching `{ name: deluser }` for the value you are providing. In all likelihood, you actually issued the same request multiple times, and initially it would have been `{ n: 1, ok: 1 }` indicating that `1` ( or possibly a larger number of matches ) document was matched and removed. The `ok: 1` of course means there was no error.

Comment: If you think the data is still in the collection, then whatever you are supplying to `req.body.usernamedel` is not actuallly what you think it is. Check your collection, and then also check the input you are providing with something like `console.log(deluser)` and see what the actual input value being sent really is.

Comment: As a final beginner note, you are using `mongoose` and that means your `User` model is expecting "by default" to see a collection named `users`. If your actual collection is named `user` or even `User` in MongoDB, then there is another way to tell mongoose to use that name instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Note: Use appropriate http verbs according to the task. Please do not use POST for DELETE operation. This will lead to inconsistent REST implementation.*

I hope below code will solve will your query.

```
app.delete("/delete", (req, res, next){
    const userToDelete = req.params.username;
    User.findOneAndRemove({name: userToDelete})
    .then(deletedUser => res.json(deletedUser))
    .catch(err => next(err));
});
```